# sbt: Can't run interactively from mintty on cygwin

Tags: shell, scala, terminal, cygwin, sbt

When I run sbt interactively from a DOS shell or from a cygwin bash terminal, it functions just fine.  However, when I try to run from my preferred mintty terminal, sbt doesn't respond to my commands until I send it an end of file (control-) and sbt exits.

TERM is set to cygwin when I'm using the bash terminal, and it's xterm when I'm using mintty.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: For me, it actually did not work just fine under Cygwin (under Windws 7), I have the same problem of having to send the end-of-line character explicitly. The accepted answer fixes the issue though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It ends up that by doing the opposite of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468967/two-problems-with-sbt-in-cygwin-vista/4469170#4469170), I added the `-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal` java option to my sbt startup script to fix the problem.

Comment: This fix also works for other java applications, such as grails and gradle.