# How to set system property jline.terminal (to fix no echo while typing on cygwin's mintty)?

Tags: sbt, mintty

I've started using sbt on `cygwin,` but had a problem that my typing would not echo in `console`.

Following this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468967/two-problems-with-sbt-in-cygwin-vista), sbt now echos, e.g.:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from D:\cygwin\home\Administrator\scala-2.11.2\coursera\example\project\project
[info] Loading project definition from D:\cygwin\home\Administrator\scala-2.11.2\coursera\example\project
[info] Set current project to progfun-example (in build file:/D:/cygwin/home/Administrator/scala-2.11.2/coursera/example/)
> ; eval System.setProperty("jline.terminal", "scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal")
[info] ans: java.lang.String = jline.UnixTerminal
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_67).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import example.Lists._
import example.Lists._

scala>
```

I tried to automate this fix by entering the line `export SBT_OPTS="-Djline.terminal=scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal"` in `~/.sbtconfig`, but I may not be using the correct syntax, as echoing doesn't seem to work.

How to get `sbt console` to use `; eval System.setProperty("jline.terminal", "scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal")` automatically?

Answer (score 2):

There's so much to discover in sbt...

```
> inspect initialize
[info] Setting: Unit = ()
[info] Description:
[info]  A convenience setting for performing side-effects during initialization.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  */*:initialize
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:153
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:initialize
[info]  {.}/*:initialize
[info]  */*:initialize
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:initialize
```

You can leverage `initialize` that's called *for performing side-effects during initialization*. With the following in `~/.sbt/0.13/default.sbt` you could achieve executing `System.setProperty`:

```
initialize := {
  System.setProperty("jline.terminal", "scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal")
}
```

When in sbt shell execute `eval sys.props("jline.terminal")` to check it out. It works fine in `console` (drop `eval` when calling `sys.props`).

Comment: Could you explain how does your suggestion automates?

(As a Scala neubee) all I can understand is that I have to type something every-time I start sbt. Is my understanding wrong, and I can actually enter your suggestion in some sbt initialization file to have the action perform automatically when sbt starts?

Comment: See my update to the answer. Open `~/.sbt/0.13/default.sbt` and copy the lines with `initialize`. Start `sbt`.

Comment: Could you explain how does your suggestion automates?

(As a Scala neubee) If I understand you correctly, I need to create a build.sbt in each project, and put therein the line you suggests, viz.:

$ cat build.sbt 
initialize := {
  System.setProperty("jline.terminal", "scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal")
}

Doing so produces "[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.tools.jline.UnixTerminal"  (and no echoing of typing)

Comment: See https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki/Terminal-Factory-Configuration where you can find possible values to control your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, @Jacek. However, for the time being I stopped using `sbt/scala`on `Cygwin` and cannot evaluate your solution: thus cannot green the `v` sign.